# Recursive print within std::cout

Tags: c++, while-loop

The input is N spaced integers. You have to read the input and print the input backwards. Source:(https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/arrays-introduction/problem?isFullScreen=false)

One of the solutions is:

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    int N,i=0;
    std::cin>>N;
    int *A = new int[N];
    while(std::cin>>A[i++]);
    // We have now iterated through the input and stored the 
    // integers in a dynamically allocated array.


    // This line apparently prints out the Array (size N) backwards.
    while(std::cout<<A[--N]<<' ' && N);
    delete[] A;
    return 0;
}
```

How does `while(std::cout<<A[--N]<<' ' && N);` print out the array A backwards?

How does it know to stop running the while loop?

What does the expression `' ' && N` do? My intuition of `&&` tells me that it should equate to `TRUE` or `FALSE`, but what does `' '` have to do with Boolean?

Comment: Also, if anyone could say, why dynamic allocating an array is so much more beneficial than not using it?

Comment: Sites like hackerrank will teach you a lot of tricks (with unreadable/unmaintainable code), they will not teach you proper C++. --N  works because of operator precedence and the &&  N is another trick that avoids printing out an extra space character at the end and will make the whole expression return 0 and end the loop. Anyway First learn C++ from a good source (book or https://www.learncpp.com/ is pretty decent), and stay away from competitive coding sites until you know more about C++ and can follow at a bit of its guidelines : https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines

Comment: @PepijnKramer Propably I am wrong, but I think << has a higher precedence that && so "&& N" the stoping condition, because cout will not go to fail state.

Comment: @KianVaru What mean with dynamic allocation is more beneficial? I would say it is the only possibility to define an array with runtime defined size.

Comment: *"You have to"* -- no, I am pretty sure I do not have to. If this is copied from the assignment **you** were given, please format it as a quotation. Also ask yourself if this quotation is even helpful to the question. It looks like your question revolves around one line of code. The question would be better if you forgot your assignment and focused on that one line of code. A [mre] might look more like `int main() { int A[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}; int N = 5; while(std::cout<<A[--N]<<' ' && N); }` -- i.e. provide the minimal code context for that line to function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `<<` operator (even though it's overloaded for output streams and is no longer a bitwise shift) has [higher precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) than the `&&` operator. Thus, we can add parentheses to your `while` statement to make it clearer:

```cpp
    while ( (std::cout << A[--N] << ' ') && N )
        ;
```

The expression within the added parentheses will, on each loop, decrement the value of `N` (so, on the first loop, that will be reduced to the original value minus 1 – which is the index to the last element of the allocated array), output the integer element at that index, then output a space. The result of that 'chained' operation will be a reference to `std::cout`; that has an `operator bool()`, which returns `true` if the output succeeded and `false` in the event (unlikely, in the given code) of failure. That (probably) true value is then combined with the result of converting `N` to a Boolean value – and *that* conversion will yield `true1 for an non-zero value and` false` for zero … so the loop will stop when the index has been decrement to zero (referencing the first element of the array).

When that `N` *has* reached zero, we no longer need to run the (empty) loop, because the output will already have been performed by the expression on the left of the `&&` operator.

Answer (score 1):

The statement is easier to understand with parentheses :

```
while((std::cout << A[--N] << ' ') && N);
```

The space character `' '` is fed to the `std::cout` stream and has nothing to do with the logic operator `&&`.
The unary operator `--` will decrement N before any access to it.
The loop will stop when N reach 0, which will make the `&&` logic operation evaluate to false.